# Python IP address prefix matching

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the following ranges of IP prefixes `10.[0-255], 192.168, 172.[16-31]` with the following regex statements:

```
if not ((re.match("^10\.([01][0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$", event["vpcprefix"]))
        or (event["vpcprefix"] == "192.168")
        or (re.match("^172\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])$", event["vpcprefix"]))):
            #throw error, not matched
```

However, every time I try to run this against the test case `10.10` it throws an error. I'm not sure why, I can't find any errors in my statements.

Comment: [I cannot repro
 any issues](https://ideone.com/V8Y67T). Please check the `event["..."]`.

Comment: If you are getting entire IP in `event["vpcprefix"]` with 4 octets then using of `$` is wrong

Comment: @rock321987 as stated it's only getting the local reserved VPC prefix of the IP address (i.e. the first 2 bytes)

Comment: post the data of `event["vpcprefix"]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the code provided should only go through if it *doesn't* match, not if it does ```if not (False or False or False): error```

Comment: May not be relevant, but mark your regex strings with `r''` prefix.

Comment: @C14L Never done that, any reason for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three patterns. Clearly only the first has any chance of being true, and within that the closest option between the `|`'s is `[01][0-9][0-9]`. But that's three digits, and `10` is two. Consider `[01]?[0-9]?[0-9]`.

Comment: Thank you, my regex was set up to match 010, not 10.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
if not ((event["vpcprefix"].split('.')[0] == '10')
        or (event["vpcprefix"] == "192.168")
        or (event["vpcprefix"].split('.')[0] == '172')):
            #do stuff
```

don't think you really need the regex here.

Comment: So I can put whatever I want after the ```.```? It needs to match a range of numbers following the first dot. Definitely needs regex.